# Avoid UnexpectedRollbackException with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've got a project with Spring Boot (2.3.3.RELEASE), Spring Data JPA (2.3.3.RELEASE) and Hibernate (5.4.20).

I'm trying to recover from DataIntegrityViolationException which happens after trying to save an Entity which violates a database constraint. For example:

```java
@Transactional
public void doSomething() {

  // save some data into the database

  try {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("test");

    // This method fails because of a constraint
    userService.save(user);
  } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    LOGGER.info("Exception caught. Trying to recover...", e);
  }

  // continue doing other things
}
```

As I've caught the exception, when `doSomething` methods ends I expect that Spring would commit the changes. However, Spring throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

As far as I've understood, Hibernate has marked the transaction as rollback-only when the integrity violation has happened and as a result Spring aborts the transaction.

I've tried to avoid this behaviour by adding `@Transactional` annotation with `noRollbackFor` attribute in the `userService.save` method, but it has been useless for this case.

I could create a new transaction for the `userService.save` method adding `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` annotation. However, I want to keep all the changes in the same transaction.

Using plain JDBC there is no problem to recover from a `DataIntegrityViolationException` and commit the changes after all. ¿Is there any way to change this behaviour with Hibernate?

I've created a demo project in Github to check this behaviour: https://github.com/wearearima/hibernate-rollback

Comment: Try to use `userRepository.save(user)` instead of `userRepository.saveAndFlush(user)`

Comment: I don't understand! There is a data integration issue at a transaction and you want hibernate to commit it without any exception? No way. You can also catch UnexpectedRollbackException and do something then!

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi This change only postpones the error. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @OnurBaştürk The thing is that there might be an integrity issue with an insert in this use case. If the integrity error happens, I don't want to abort the whole use case. Because of that, I catch the exception and continue executing the method and commit the changes when the method has finished. I expected that Spring would do the commit, but it doesn't work with Hibernate. It's true that this situation might be unlikely but it's something that I can manage with jdbc instead of hibernate.

Comment: I see! Then you can divide that method into two methods. Save the others in another transactional method. And then call user save method in another transaction

Comment: @OnurBaştürk that defeats the purpose of what he is trying to do, as he said: `However, I want to keep all the changes in the same transaction.` I've encountered this situation myself and sadly have never found a good solution.

Comment: so what is the proposed solution ? what did you end up doing ?  @telle

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is not possible. Hibernate will always mark transaction as rollbackonly, when PersistenceException happens during flush due to "the persistence context might contain wrong data after a constraint violation" (quote of Christian Beikov)